# horizontal jquery menu with subsectons

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I need some help. I've looked everywhere but I do think what i'm looking for is a little unique.

I'm trying to make a menu that when you click on a menu option a group of options. That bit I got, i think. what im trying to achieve now is getting it to allow the children of the submenu slide in-between the line of links directly. kind of like an horizontal accordion menu, with the twist of having all the top menu links in a row rather then vertically.

the action, click on topmenu item and a submenu(s) links will appear. if a submenu link is clicked, that link with appear the sub-submenu items corresponding to that original link and hiding all but itself and its parents.

im not sire if im explaining it right. my head is a little brain-dead from trying to solve this issue all day and im about to cave in.

this is an example of what im trying to achieve:

[image]

if you want go here to see what i have done http://jsfiddle.net/pi_mai/zuU5M/
So i'm trying to make a menu with this HTML code ( i've remove many link items to shorten the code ):

```
    <nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
        <li class="topmenu-item-1"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
        <li class="topmenu-item-2"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="submenu topmenu-item-1">
        <li class="submenu-item-1"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item-2"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="subsubmenu submenu-item-1">
        <li class="submenu-item-1"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item-2"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="submenu topmenu-item-1">
        <li class="submenu-item-7"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item-8"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="submenu topmenu-item-2">
        <li class="submenu-item-1"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item-2"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="submenu topmenu-item-3">
        <li class="submenu-item-1"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item-2"><a href="" class="topmenu-link">top menu</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

.

```
$('.topmenu > li').on('click',function(){
        var itemClass = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log(itemClass)
        $('.submenu').not(this).removeClass('toggle');
        $('.submenu.' + itemClass ).toggleClass('toggle');
        $('.subsubmenu.toggle').siblings().removeClass('toggle')
    });
    $('.submenu > li').on('click',function(){
        var itemClass = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log(itemClass)
        $('.subsubmenu').not(this).removeClass('toggle');
        $('.subsubmenu.' + itemClass ).toggleClass('toggle');
    });
```

Can anyone help me?

EDIT

I think I have the solution, just need to add animation but it's working overall and that to me is fantastic!

```
function menuTap( $this ){

    var thisClass = $this.attr('class');

    if( $this.parent().hasClass("top-menu") ){
        $('.sub-menu.' + thisClass ).animate().toggleClass('hide');
        $('.sub-menu' + ':not(.' + thisClass + '), .sub-sub-menu' ).addClass('hide');
    };

    if( $this.parent().hasClass("sub-menu") ){
        console.log( $this.attr('class') + ' li was clicked')
        $('.sub-sub-menu.' + thisClass ).toggleClass('hide');
        $('.sub-sub-menu' + ':not(.' + thisClass + ')' ).addClass('hide');
    };

}

$('.top-menu li, .sub-menu li').on('click',function(){
    menuTap( $(this) );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One major hurdle is your HTML structure. Nearly all menus will have something like this, where submenus are nested inside their parents:

```
<ul class="topmenu">
  <li><a></a>
    <ul class="submenu">...</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Whereas you have this, with submenus as siblings of their parents:

```
<ul class="topmenu">
  ...
</ul>

<ul class="submenu">
  ...
</ul>
```

It's simpler to call elements based on a parent-child relationship than by classes or sibling relationships.

Here's a start. I'm out of time for now. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zuU5M/1/

Comment: Normal menu structure wasn't the best solution to this problem as it was something i had originally tried to accomplish. The method I have chossen is so that sub-submenus can rip apart submenus. with the typical menu system the sub-submenu would just appear at the bottom.

Comment: Actually, the whole point of this structure is so that submenus appear where they fall in the parent list. How they appear is up to your CSS and jQuery specifics. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

please check below code. i have edited html, css and javascript.

## Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.topmenu-link').click(function(){
        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('open')){
            jQuery('.topmenu-link').removeClass('open');
            jQuery('.submenu-part').stop(true,true).slideUp();
            jQuery(this).parent('.topmenu-item').children('.submenu-part').stop(true,true).slideDown();
            jQuery(this).addClass('open');  
        }else{
            jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
            jQuery('.submenu-part').stop(true,true).slideUp();
        }
    });
    
     });
</script> 
<!--script end-->
```

## Css code

```
<!--css start-->
<style>
body{
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 20px;  
    color:white;
    font-family: arial;
}
a{
    color: aqua;
}
.clear{clear:both;}
.topmenu{
    background-color: green;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li.topmenu-item{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative;
    zoom:1;
    
}
.topmenu-link{
    padding: 20px;
    display:block;
}
.submenu-part{
    background:#060;
    width:200px;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:59px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
.submenu-item-link{
    margin:5px 0px;
    display:block;
}
.submenu-item-link a{
    margin:8px 0px;
    display:block;
}
        
</style>
<!--css end-->
```

## Html code

```
<!--html content start-->
<nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
        <li class="topmenu-item">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="topmenu-link">top menu 1</a>
            <ul class="submenu-part">
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 1</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 2</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 3</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="topmenu-item">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="topmenu-link">top menu 2</a>
            <ul class="submenu-part">
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 1</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="topmenu-item">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="topmenu-link">top menu 3</a>
            <ul class="submenu-part">
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 1</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 2</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="topmenu-item">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="topmenu-link">top menu 4</a>
            <ul class="submenu-part">
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 1</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 2</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 3</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 4</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 5</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 6</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 7</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item-link"><a href="" >top menu 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="clear"></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!--html content end-->
```